# Ionic 2: Improve gif-app smoothness

Tags: ionic2

I have about 600MB of GIF's I have hosted outside my app and I point to these GIFS by URL (for example: my-gif-api.com/15.gif).

```
<img src="http://www.my-gif-api.com/15.gif">
```

My app has a screen with like 6 animations (GIFS) in one page, and the rendering is very slow and not smooth. Sometimes even 3 animations make the app really slow. Is there any way to improve the performance in such case?

Comment: Maybe add some sort of lazy loading for the images?

Comment: The app works slow after loading the images because the screen can handle only up to 60 fps a second if I understood correctly.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to call the gifs?

Comment: @gerdi it's simply `<img src="http://www.my-gif-api.com/15.gif">`

Comment: This might be a very wrong answer but it might be that the server is slow .. i dont know , but it might be better to implement a GET call and then save the images to SQL storage and then call them from the device itself, removing them as you navigate away. Just tested with 6 large gifs on crappy android and it seems fine.

Comment: What are the gif sizes you have tested? (KB)

Comment: total on page 2.88MB , there is no identifiable performance hit. gifs are stored in `assets/imgs` folder. Maybe create a page with gif files stored locally and see if there is a difference in performance

Comment: pause the gif animation when scrolling, otherwise will cause the whole app will slow.

Answer (score 0):

I was on the same lag problem using ionic 1 . I solved it using this package 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-loader-angular,It only display the gif once its completely downloaded from the server.

```
ImageLoader.loadImage('your-gif-url').then(function(loadedSrc) {

      gif.spinnerShow = false; // I'm using gif.show to show a spinner inside the div

    });
```

Hope it helps ;)